# How to pass and convert asp.net TextBox String to a Float Variable in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to pass and convert two asp.net TextBoxes to a JavaScript Float.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var Jvar1 = parseFloat(getElementById("<%= LogTextBox.ClientID %>").value);
var Jvar2 = parseFloat(getElementById("<%= LatTextBox.ClientID %>").value);
```

This my Asp.net code:

```
<asp:Table ID="tbsiteinfo" runat="server">

<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="left" CssClass="paddingLeftRight5px"  >
<asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server" Width="220px" Text="Lat"></asp:Label>
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="left" CssClass="paddingLeftRight5px" >
<asp:TextBox Width="200px" ID="LatTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="left" CssClass="paddingLeftRight5px"  >
<asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Width="220px" Text="Log"></asp:Label>
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="left" CssClass="paddingLeftRight5px" >
<asp:TextBox Width="200px" ID="LogTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>

</asp:Table>
```

For some reason the values are not coming up at all. Any ideas? thanks so much for the help.

Comment: It should be document.getElementById.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` is the function of [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document) object, so you need to use it like `document.getElementById('id')`. So your syntax would be.

```
var Jvar1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%= LogTextBox.ClientID %>").value);
```